# Attempt to install testlink with postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, pgadmin-4, testlink

I was able to upload it to xampp and that I could run it on the page to start its installation [See that it could already be uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE26P.png)
Now that I continue with the installation I put this data [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWCnq.png)
I make sure they are the correct ones in my database [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/631Da.png)
Then I get this error [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuA5M.png)

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: pg_close(): Argument #1 ($connection) must be of type ?PgSql\Connection, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\vendor\adodb\adodb-php\drivers\adodb-postgres64.inc.php:903 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\vendor\adodb\adodb-php\drivers\adodb-postgres64.inc.php(903): pg_close(false) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\vendor\adodb\adodb-php\adodb.inc.php(2901): ADODB_postgres64->_close() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\lib\functions\database.class.php(487): ADOConnection->Close() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\install\installNewDB.php(240): database->close() #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\vendor\adodb\adodb-php\drivers\adodb-postgres64.inc.php on line 903
```

from what I found is that php is not well installed, which it is [PHP well installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWPgc.png)
And the second thing is that the credentials are incorrect and I already tried several ways to try to get them to accept them and it doesn't work, I hope someone can help me

I tried not putting port and see if they were the correct passwords

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that testlink has an error with php 8, the problem has already been raised on the official page, only it has about 15 days to be raised, Check if this incident is resolved [PHP 8.1 LDAP Authentication: ldap_connect_bind() fails](http://mantis.testlink.org/view.php?id=9235) , which means that php 8 is not working with testlink , but the newest xampp already brings php 8 by default.
The answer is to save the files:

- Folder 'Testlink' what did you create inside xampp>>htdocs
- The file 'php.ini' what is inside xampp>>php

Since these files should have been modified beforehand in order to make testlink work.
After that uninstall xampp and install xampp but a previous version, which worked for me: [xampp_7.4.33](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/7.4.33/xampp-windows-x64-7.4.33-0-VC15-installer.exe/download)  , After putting the files that you saved before uninstalling xampp mentioned above, you put them in their respective folders. And I Would stay.